# CRUD on BindingSource in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` and a `BindingSource bs` populated using `bs.DataSource = list;` where `list` is a `BindingList<Item>`.

All I want is to have each changed `Item` notified that it is changed, and each deleted item notified that it is deleted. Or instead, I would like to have access to changed, new and deleted items after user edits the grid and presses the button.

**Edit**:

```
public abstract class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged { .......
public Item()
{
    Id = IdCounter++;
    Pairs = new HashSet<int>();
    State = ItemState.NEW;
    Name = "#noname";
    Note = "";
    PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Item_PropertyChanged);
}

void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SetChanged();
}

/* nastaví příznak, že se něco změnilo - to následně vyvolá UPDATE (při použití SQL úložiště) */
public void SetChanged()
{
    State = ItemState.CHANGED;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll want to listen for the [`ListChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.listchanged.aspx) event on your `BindingList<Item>` or `BindingSource bs`.  In the [`ListChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs.aspx), the [`ListChangedType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs.listchangedtype.aspx) with have specific details about what changed:

> Reset - Much of the list has changed. Any listening controls should
>   refresh all their data from the list.
>
> **ItemAdded** - An item added to the
>   list. NewIndex contains the index of the item that was added.
>
> **ItemDeleted** - An item deleted from the list. NewIndex contains the
>   index of the item that was deleted.
>
> ItemMoved - An item moved within
>   the list. OldIndex contains the previous index for the item, whereas
>   NewIndex contains the new index for the item.
>
> **ItemChanged** - An item
>   changed in the list. NewIndex contains the index of the item that was
>   changed.

I bolded the ones you mentioned.

**Update**

Ok, so this is what the `Item` class should look like:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private int _Id;
   private HashSet<int> _Pairs;
   private ItemState _State;
   private String _ItemName;
   private String _Note;

   public Item()
   {
      Id = IdCounter++;
      Pairs = new HashSet<int>();
      State = ItemState.NEW;
      Name = "#noname";
      Note = "";      
   }

   public int Id
   {
      get { return _Id; }
      set
      {
         if(_Id != value)
         {
            _Id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
         }
      }
   }

   ... Implement other properties like above/below

   // Dont use 'Name' as a property type
   public String ItemName
   {
      get { return _ItemName; }
      set
      {
         if(_ItemName!= value)
         {
            _ItemName= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemName");
         }
      }
   }

   ...

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler prop_changed = PropertyChanged;
      if (prop_changed != null)
      {
         prop_changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
}
```

Then when you attach to you BindingList you should get the updates.  Then you can change the state of your item when you receive those events or through databinding.

Comment: When the item is edited this event is not fired. I need to detect attribute changes of list items.

Comment: When you mean edited, do you mean they change the value in the DataGridView and then unfocus current item, it doesnt fire?  Your list items will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order for this to work.

Comment: Yes! That's it but I have implemented that interface but nothing gets fired, :-( In other words, my Item implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` but PropertyChanged event is not fired on "focus-lost".

Answer (score 0):

There is a CurrentItemChange event you can listen to on a BindingSource

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx